# SQL Server After Insert Trigger not copying all rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables in the same DB on SQL Server 2008. When I insert a row to the first I want some fields to be copied to the second one. I made a trigger that is doing that but the problem is that sometimes when I add 2 rows very fast it is copying only one of them.

What is wrong with my code?

```
USE [DB_NAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerName]
   ON  [dbo].[table1]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO dbo.table2(L_UID, L_Mode, C_Name, C_Logon)
      SELECT ins.L_UID, ins.L_Mode, ins.C_Name, temp.C_Remark AS Logon FROM INSERTED AS ins
         INNER JOIN dbo.tEmploye AS temp
         ON (temp.L_UID = ins.L_UID)
      WHERE temp.C_Remark IS NOT NULL

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost certainly has nothing to do with "adding very fast".  My best guess is that the rows your inserting don't always join with tEmploye.  Try making it an outer join (if possible) and see if you continue to have these so-called missing rows, or if you get null in your C_Logon column in table2 (odd names for tables I must say --- such obfuscation  makes figuring out a possible solution more difficult)

Comment: I was testing always with the same two rows of data. When I do it slowly it works OK, when I do it fast I got two entries in first table and 1 in the second. Because of that I know that INNER JOIN is matching and C_Logon is not null. I am testing this with a card reader and I have only two users there.